# Ask for suggestions on deploying ElasticSearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

[Ask for suggestions]Recently we have bought 5 powerful machines to build our Elasticsearch cluster.

Here is hardware list of each machine:

**cpu : 54 cores
memory:  384GB
disk: 800G*3 SSD + 1.2TB*20 HDD**

Any suggestions or best practices of how to deploy Elasticsearch cluster on these machines to maximize resources and offer the best service available? One or multi ES instances per host?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of data are you looking to index? How available does the data need to be? Where will the data come from and where will it be needed? You see a pattern here?

Comment: We use this cluster to store and index application log, machine log, and monitoring log，now about 5 TB a day. Logs are consumed from Kafka by Flume. These log data should be kept 7 days. We use these log to detect error and exception reporting in near real time. So we can endure some data loss  but  need a really good indexing and searching performance. @sramalingam24W

Comment: That is a tough one. With the amount of data you need to index everyday, i would lean towards multiple instances (may be one for each log?). Of course does your client app need to combine results from these logs and how consistent are the log sizes are something you would need to consider.